# SQL Distinct не работает

Tags: sql

Не получается получить уникальные результаты, вместо этого получаю 9 идентичных копий одного юзера:

```
select DISTINCT "users".*, "permissions"."slug", "roles"."name"
from "users"
    left join "role_user" on "users"."id" = "role_user"."user_id"
    left join "roles" on "roles"."id" = "role_user"."role_id"
    left join "permission_role" on "roles"."id" = "permission_role"."role_id"
    left join "permissions" on "permissions"."id" = "permission_role"."permission_id"
    left join "email_user" on "users"."id" = "email_user"."user_id"
    left join "emails" on "emails"."id" = "email_user"."email_id"
where exists (select * from "roles"
    inner join "role_user" on "roles"."id" = "role_user"."role_id"
    where "users"."id" = "role_user"."user_id" and (LOWER(roles.name) = 'administrator'))
and "users"."deleted_at" is null
group by "users"."id", "permissions"."slug", "roles"."name"
order by roles.name ASC
limit 20 offset 0;
```

Всю голову уже сломал, где может быть ошибка?

Comment: Уточните заголовок

Comment: Видимо в выводимых записях не все поля идентичные.

Comment: А ничего что выводите ВСЕ поля user, а группируете только по id?

Comment: Данный запрос может вернуть 9 копий одного пользователя только в одном случае - у него несколько ролей и/или permissions.slug. И да, каждая роль или slug порождает новую запись. Если вы хотите что бы пользователь строго один вы должны убрать из group by поля не из таблицы users и решить какие значения вы хотите получить в колонках ролей и прав при условии, что запись у вас всего одна, а значений для вывода много (к ним надо применить какую либо агрегатную функцию)